# Show Viewbag data in Google Map using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have json file for a City which contain Many Interesting places name,Short-text, Geocoordinates and Image. I deserialize this json data in Controller. Now I want to show this information as Viewbag in the View in google map.Well I am trying but there are lots of error in my code and nothing work at all. My sample json data is as follows-

```
{
"poi":[
{
      "Name": "Nordertor",
      "Shorttext": "The Nordertor is an old town gate in Flensburg, Germany, which was built around 1595. Today the landmark is used as a symbol for Flensburg.",
      "GeoCoordinates": {
        "Longitude": 9.43004861,
        "Latitude": 54.79541778
      },
      "Images": [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/Nordertor_im_Schnee_%28Flensburg%2C_Januar_2014%29.JPG/266px-Nordertor_im_Schnee_%28Flensburg%2C_Januar_2014%29.JPG"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Naval Academy Mürwik",
      "Shorttext": "The Naval Academy Mürwik is the main training establishment for all German Navy officers and replaced the German Imperial Naval Academy in Kiel.\nIt is located at Mürwik which is a part of Germany's most northern city, Flensburg. Built on a small hill directly by the coast, it overlooks the Flensburg Fjord. The main building of the academy is known for its beautiful architecture and location, and is often named the \"Red Castle\".",
      "GeoCoordinates": {
        "Longitude": 9.45944444,
        "Latitude": 54.815
      },
      "Images": [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fb/MSM-hauptgebaeude.jpg/400px-MSM-hauptgebaeude.jpg"
      ]
    },

    {
      "Name": "Flensburg Firth",
      "Shorttext": "Flensburg Firth or Flensborg Fjord  is the westernmost inlet of the Baltic Sea. It forms part of the border between Germany to the south and Denmark to the north. Its length is either 40 or 50 km, depending to the definition of its limits. It has the largest surface of all Förden and East Jutland Fjorde, which are a special type of inlets, different from geological fjords.\nTwo peninsulas, Broager peninsula on the northern side and Holnis peninsula on the southern side divide the inlet in an outer and an inner part. West of them, near the Danish coast, there are two small Islands called Okseøer.\nOn the Danish side, outer part of the northern limits of the firth is formed by the island of Als with the town of Sønderborg. Towards the west, continuing on the Danish side are Broager, Egernsund, Gråsten, Rinkenæs, Sønderhav, and Kollund.\nIn Germany at the Danish border there is Harrislee, at the inner end of the inlet the town of Flensburg, east of it on the southern shore the town of Glücksburg and the villages Munkbrarup, Langballig, Westerholz, Quern, Steinberg, Niesgrau, Gelting, and Nieby.\n\n",
      "GeoCoordinates": {
        "Longitude": 9.42901993,
        "Latitude": 54.7959404
      },
      "Images": [
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Flensborg_Fjord_ved_bockholmwik.jpg/400px-Flensborg_Fjord_ved_bockholmwik.jpg"
      ]
    }



    ]
```

}

In the Controller class I deserilize in the following way-

```
 public ActionResult Index(City objCityModel)
    {
        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        return View();
    }

public ActionResult PlaceInformation(City objCityModel)
    {

        string name = objCityModel.Name;
        ViewBag.Title = name;

        var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/POI_Json/" + name + ".json"));

        RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);
        List<Poi> mycities = new List<Poi>();

        foreach (var item in json.poi)
        {
            Poi obj = new Poi()
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                Shorttext = item.Shorttext,
                GeoCoordinates = item.GeoCoordinates,
                Images = item.Images,

            };
            mycities.Add(obj);
        }

        ViewBag.Cities = mycities;

        return View();
    }
```

Now in the View I want to use this data. But I ma not how to proceed with it. I wrote some comments beside the code.

```
  @model  PoiFinder.Models.City

  <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">

 <div class="col-lg-10">
     <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Back</a>
        </li>

    </ol>
</div>

 </div>
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>GoogleMap</title>


 </head>
 <body>

   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- This css is to ensure that the google map contols (zoom bar etc) show and size correctly. -->
   <style>
    #map_canvas img {
        max-width: none;
    }
    </style>

   <!-- This css is to give a nice big popup "info window" when a marker is clicked on the map -->
<style>
    .infoDiv {
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        background-color: white;
    }
   </style>


  <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 600px;"></div>


   @section scripts {
      <section class="scripts">

        <script type="text/javascript">


            $(document).ready(function () {
                Initialize();
            });


            function Initialize() {


                google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
                @ViewBag.Title = new google.maps.LatLng(53.408841, -2.981397); @*@ Here I want to get the name of City@*@


                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: Liverpool,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.G_NORMAL_MAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.40091, -2.994464);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Tate Gallery'
                });


                marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png')



                $.each(ViewBag.Cities, function (i, item) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        'position': new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude, item.GeoCoordinates.Latitude),
                        'map': map,
                        'title': item.Name
                    });




                     marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png')


                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: "<div class='infoDiv'><h2>" + item.Name+ "</h2>" + "<div><h4>Short-Text: " + item.Shorttext + "</h4></div> +<div><img src=item@image </div>"
                    });


                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    });

                })
            }


        </script>
     </section>
   }

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: In your $.each(ViewBag.Cities, function (i, item) {}, check "item" value by adding one alert like alert(item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude) and see any values showing. If it is not returning anything please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Example looks like this. You can build upon it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ShowSuppliersOnGoogleMap();
});

function ShowSuppliersOnGoogleMap() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42, -97)
     , zoom: 4
     , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     , mapTypeControl: true
     , scrollwheel: false
};

var mapExists = document.getElementById("supplierMapCanvas");
if (mapExists) {
    // init map
    console.log('Initialise map...');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("supplierMapCanvas"), mapOptions);
    getSupplierlistAndCreateGoogleMap(map);
}
}

function getSupplierlistAndCreateGoogleMap(map) {
var params={};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/GetSupplierInformationForGoogleMap",        
    data: AddAntiForgeryToken(params),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.responseText != "") {
            CreateSupplierMarker(data, map);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        logError(ajaxOptions, thrownError);
    }
});
}

function CreateSupplierMarker(data, maps) {
var locations = [[]];
locations = data;
var total_locations = locations.length;
var map = maps;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
if (locations[0][0] != "NO-DATA") {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var supplierName = locations[i][0];
        var address = locations[i][1];
        var z = i;
        // use the Google API to translate addresses to GPS coordinates
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        if (geocoder) {
            console.log('Got a new instance of Google Geocoder object');
            console.log('Looking up ' + supplierName + ' at address ' + address);
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, makeCallback(infoWindow, supplierName, z));
        }
        else {
            console.log('Failed to instantiate Google Geocoder object');
        }
    }
}
else { console.log('Failed to retrieve supplier list'); }

function makeCallback(infoWindow, supplierName, zIndex) {
    var geocodeCallBack = function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            console.log('Received result: lat:' + latitude + ' long:' + longitude);
            var content = '<div class="map-content"><h3>' + supplierName + '</h3></div>';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                map: map,
                title: supplierName,
                zIndex: zIndex
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function (marker, content) {
                return function () { infoWindow.setContent(content); infoWindow.open(map, marker); }
            })(marker, content));

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(15);
            });

        }
        else {
            console.log('No results found: ' + status);
        }
    }
    return geocodeCallBack;
}
 }
```

For your help Server side code looks like

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult GetSupplierInformationForGoogleMap()
    {
        string[][] supplierDetails = null;
        try
        {
            logger.Info("Get Supplier Information For GoogleMap");
            SupplierMapManager supplierMapManager = new SupplierMapManager();
            supplierDetails = supplierMapManager.RetrieveSupplierList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            logger.Info("Get Supplier Information For GoogleMap failed");
            throw;
        }
        return Json(supplierDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible without ajax. Because at previous I tried with Ajax but there was lot of problem in referencing. So now I tried with javascript.

Comment: I have edited my answer. there you can see the full picture of how we are doing ajax call. If you are implementing it correctly AJAX wiil do the trick

Comment: @Ok. But this is totally different what I want to do. I have  ViewBag message like Name, Shottext and Images and these I want to show on view. I wrote in my code how I want to proceed

Comment: In the above example GetSupplierInformationForGoogleMap doing the server side call to get the details. In your case you need to get your details using that function.

Comment: I have edited my answer, there controller code looks like that

Comment: I have modified my question in the view section, could you please have a look and tell me is it poosible in this way. Because I do not need to configure server side at this moment. I have just a sample data  inside the appdata. And I want to pass these data as ViewBag just according to my contrller class

Comment: By doing slight changes in your current code you can implement map as per i said. Without assigning it to viewbag in your PlaceInformation function you can return your result as json result as i shown above. Rest of them are almost same

Comment: But My question was to pass the ViewBag Datas

Comment: Did you check that whether you getting values in your Viewbag or not in your script? If you are getting values check CreateSupplierMarker in my answer section. There in the place of locations give your viewbag as a replace.

Comment: Frankly speaking I am very new handling this case. So for me It is really very difficult to modify someones code. As I said I just want to modify my code. And I am trying to make it with Javascript. I used same controller data in my other program. That time it was working fine. Niw I want to pass these datas in Google Map. But Failed could not not succed

Comment: I am using  this link to modify my code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/629913/Google-Maps-in-MVC-with-Custom-InfoWindow . But here they use static data. But I want Get My Viewbag data instead of fixed data

Comment: In your $.each(ViewBag.Cities, function (i, item) {} check "item" value by adding one alert like alert(item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude) and see any values showing. If it is not returning anything please let me know